# Access Denied (Public Key) when creating a new user for SSH purposes

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, ssh-keys, digital-ocean

I wanted to create a new user on my digital ocean server and then log in as this user using SSH but I'm getting an access denied error. Here are the steps I tried.

On Local Machine:

```
#create a new key
ssh-keygen -b 1024 -f userblue -t dsa
chmod 600 userblue.pub

#copy the public key over to a temp dir on the target server using my root user/key
scp userblue.pub root@mytargetserver -i id_rsa:/tmp
```

Now I log into the target server as root so I can make a new user, and copy the public key to authorized_keys

```
#create a new user and make an .ssh dir for this user
useradd -m -d /home/userblue -s /bin/bash userblue 
su - userblue
cd /home/userblue
mkdir .ssh
chmod 700 .ssh
touch .ssh/authorized_keys
chmod 600 .ssh/authorized_keys

#move the public key I created and add it to authorized_keys
mv /tmp/userblue.pub /home/userblue/.ssh/
cat useable.pub >> /home/userblue/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Now I log out and go back to my local machine, using the userblue private key to log in

```
ssh userblue@mytargetserver -i userblue
```

Permission Denied (publickey)

Any idea why I'm getting Permission Denied? I tried ssh with -vvv but it's completely Greek to me. Have no idea what to look for.

Comment: using 1/ dsa 2/ "only" 1024b are two weak security choices imho. see https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/5096/rsa-vs-dsa-for-ssh-authentication-keys/46781#46781 especially the "nasty property"

Answer (score 1):

In my /etc/sshd file I had Match User but my new user I created wasn't in there, so that was why. After adding another ",User userblue" it worked!